# Android: Resources$NotFoundException at adding drawable to styles.xml

Tags: android, file, exception, splash-screen, filenotfoundexception

I have this `splash_screen.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</layer-list>
```

Then I want to add it as an `<item>` to `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

But this throws:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_screen.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070099
```

When I try:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

My code works fine and shows a screen in colorPrimary.

**How can I fix it?**

I tried rebuilding, cleaning, restarting Android Studio and every post on SO. Nothing helped.

**EDIT**

`splash_screen.xml` is **definitely** in the drawable folder.

[image]

Android Studio is suggesting the file.

My drawable folder:

[image]

Comment: could you share the screenshot of file tree in resources from android studio.

Comment: Hv u added the splashscreen xml to yoyr drawable folder?

Comment: @PrajwalW Yes, to my drawable folder.

Comment: Suggesting a file doesn't mean anything. If you need a help, post a screenshot of file tree from Android studio, res directory

Comment: @mac229 I added it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `android:drawable` instead `android:src` in your item **tag** as you did in first one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</layer-list>
```

**Besides this**, always post the full stack trace of exception. Actual exception clearly indicate the problem like below:

> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line
>   6:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
     <item>
          <bitmap
                 android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
      </item>
```

Add @drawable/your_image instead of @mipmap/your_image in your code.

Comment: Let me know whether bitmap solved your issue or nt!

Comment: Did u tried adding drawable instead of mipmap? In your src?

Comment: Yes tats good....bt also if you would hv added @drawable/yourimage instead of @mipmap/yourimage it would hv worked....tats wat i mentioned in my ans. Just check once does tat works or nt pls!

Comment: Thank u...the issue was same. It required a drawable attribute! Happy Coding!